# java.lang.NullPointerException on JSONObject

Tags: android, fragment

I am trying to retrieve data from MySQL database using JSON to be displayed in a fragment's listview in android studio but my app is stopping at run time due to java.lang.NullPointerException.Can you help me to fix this error please.
my fragment code is:

```
 package com.sawaset.rpl;

    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 Created by Sibo on 7/25/2017.
 **/

public class timetable extends Fragment {
   private String jsonResult=null;
    public String address = "http://127.0.0.1/projects/soccer/query.php";
    ListView listview;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

             View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_tab, container, false);

      listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        /*ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menus);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);*/
        accessWebService();
        return rootView;
    }

    //
    private class jsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httPost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        //
        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            String rLine = "";
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            try {
                while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer.append(rLine);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error:" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return answer;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            drawer();
        }

    }
//

    public void accessWebService() {
        jsonReadTask task = new jsonReadTask();
        task.execute(new String[]{address});
    }

    public void drawer() {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult.substring(jsonResult.indexOf("{"), jsonResult.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
           JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("teams");

            final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyarrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> map;
            if (jsonMainNode!= null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                    map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put("t_id", c.getString("t_id"));
                    map.put("t_id", c.getString("t_id"));
                    map.put("t_id", c.getString("t_id"));

                    MyarrList.add(map);

                    SimpleAdapter sAdp = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), MyarrList, R.layout.columns, new String[]{"t_id", "t_id", "t_id"}, new int[]{R.id.col1, R.id.col2, R.id.col3});
                    listview.setAdapter(sAdp);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error:" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

The logcat is shown below

```
 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9bbdd240, tid 17548
08-13 22:07:20.395 17531-17531/com.sawaset.rpl E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.sawaset.rpl, PID: 17531
                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.indexOf(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                     at com.sawaset.rpl.timetable.drawer(timetable.java:105)
                                                                     at com.sawaset.rpl.timetable$jsonReadTask.onPostExecute(timetable.java:92)
                                                                     at com.sawaset.rpl.timetable$jsonReadTask.onPostExecute(timetable.java:55)
                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:667)
                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:684)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
08-13 22:07:21.056 1280-1280/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1280: eglCreateSyncKHR(1669): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
08-13 22:07:21.847 2415-17536/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for session 2753, record source 1999, sample rate 16000, format 0x1, channel mask 0x10, flags 0
08-13 22:07:21.853 2415-17536/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -22.
08-13 22:07:21.853 2415-17536/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
08-13 22:07:21.856 2415-17536/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
08-13 22:07:27.002 2415-17536/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for session 2761, record source 1999, sample rate 16000, format 0x1, channel mask 0x10, flags 0
08-13 22:07:27.004 2415-17536/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -22.
08-13 22:07:27.006 2415-17536/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
08-13 22:07:27.007 2415-17536/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
08-13 22:07:32.099 2415-17536/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for session 2769, record source 1999, sample rate 16000, format 0x1, channel mask 0x10, flags 0
08-13 22:07:32.100 2415-17536/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -22.
```

any help is highly appreciated

Comment: You don't have server running on device itself. Run server on device **or use right address/IP.**

Comment: Thank you,I am running the app on an android emulator,how can I run the server on it?

Comment: You should rather learn networking basics - what is a localhost.

Comment: yeah,but I know well that the XAMPP server is running on my PC,so I have the access on localhost so that I am getting JSON array when tried to retrieve them using PHP

Comment: Server is running on pc not on device so it's not a localhost(on device).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) but in fact the problem is with understanding what is a localhost.

Comment: Thank you so much Selvin,this have helped me  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905650/how-do-i-get-the-local-ip-address-of-the-server-using-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.indexOf(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

`at com.sawaset.rpl.timetable.drawer(timetable.java:105)`

That means that at **line 105** in **`timetable.drawer`** there is an null object reference. I believe that is the following line of code:

`final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyarrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();`

The only time that `MyarrList` is assigned any values is inside of your `if (jsonMainNode!= null)` check at line 107 of `timetable.drawer`. Therefore if `jsonMainNode` is equal to null, then your `MyarrList` will also be null.

As Selvin mentioned below, an error in resolving your path causing a null `jsonResult` will in turn cause a null `jsonResponse`, which will then cause a null `jsonMainNode` and throw the NullPointerException.

Comment: thank you sir,I can see that the error is not in the code,nut on the backend side so I am asking myself whether it's the mistake done on the address given as path to database

Comment: Thanks Selvin, the answer has been improved with your input.

Comment: Thank you @Randall,@Selvin ,solved it by setting an IP to my device