# Unable to get LOCAL IP address of a machine from a site which is hosted on GODADDY

Tags: php, linux, ip-address

Hai I am trying to get local IP address of the machine where the our internal portal got accessed from, i need the IP **192.168.xx.xx**, I tried using may solutions like

```
$myIp = getHostByName(getHostName());    
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']     
$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']

function getLocalIP(){
    exec("ipconfig /all", $output);
        foreach($output as $line){
            if (preg_match("/(.*)IPv4 Address(.*)/", $line)){
                $ip = $line;
                $ip = str_replace("IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . :","",$ip);
                $ip = str_replace("(Preferred)","",$ip);
            }
        }
    return $ip;
}
```

and even some more solutions from references

[How do I get the local IP address of the server using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905650/how-do-i-get-the-local-ip-address-of-the-server-using-php) ,
[how to get local computer ip address in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40670895/how-to-get-local-computer-ip-address-in-php) ,
[Get Local Machine IP Address in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684098/get-local-machine-ip-address-in-php)

But nothing works to get the desired solution? any suggestions?

Comment: I think it's impossible to get the address of the computers local IP address from a remote connection.  The IP address you will normally get is the one for your router/gateway.

Comment: ya @NigelRen i understood in windows server its possible by using ipconfig but in Linux it is not possible it seems

Comment: A local IP address is, by definition, only known locally. Since PHP runs on the server, and not locally on the client accessing the server, you cannot retrieve it with only PHP. You need something on the client, like Javascript, to get the local IP. But even that can be difficult. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194722/can-you-get-a-users-local-lan-ip-address-via-javascript However, once you know the IP in Javascript you can easily send it to your PHP server.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thank you, i will try this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you will not be able to retrieve the `local ip address` of any computer that resides behind a NAT router / firewall and especially not with PHP which runs at the server anyway so the code above would find the ip of the server.

However you can use Javascript and a feature found in `webRTC` to reveal the local IP address of a visitor to your portal. The result of which can be passed to PHP using Ajax if required. I discovered this a few weeks ago whilst investigating a connectivity issue - a site I visited was showing my public & local ip addresses. After looking at the source code and doing further research I put the following little function together - perhaps it may be of use.

```
<?php

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Get Local IP address</title>
        <script>
            const rtcpip=function( server, callback ){
                /* 
                    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/createDataChannel
                    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/createOffer
                */
                let debug=true;

                let oList={
                    google1:'stun1.l.google.com:19302',
                    google2:'stun2.l.google.com:19302',
                    google3:'stun3.l.google.com:19302',
                    google4:'stun4.l.google.com:19302',
                    kundenserver:'stun.kundenserver.de:3478',
                    mozilla:'stun.services.mozilla.com:3478',
                    notts:'stun.nottingham.ac.uk:3478'
                };
                const getserver=function(){
                    return oList.hasOwnProperty( server ) ? oList[ server ] : oList.mozilla;
                };

                let duplicates={};
                let stunsvr=getserver();
                let RTCPeerConnection=window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
                let oConstraints={ optional: [ { RtpDataChannels: true } ] };
                let oServers = { iceServers: [ { urls: 'stun:' + stunsvr } ] };

                const info=function(m){
                    if( arguments.length==1 && debug )console.info(m);
                    if( arguments.length==2 && debug )console.info(m,arguments[1]);
                };
                const candidatehandler=function( candidate ){
                    info( candidate );
                    let regex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/
                    let addr = regex.exec( candidate )[1];
                    if( duplicates[ addr ] === undefined ) callback( addr );
                    duplicates[ addr ] = true;
                };
                const icelistener=function( oIce ){
                    if( oIce.candidate ) candidatehandler.call( this, oIce.candidate.candidate );
                };
                const icedclistener=function(e){
                    let oChan=e.channel;
                        oChan.addEventListener( 'open', function( evt ){ info( evt ) }, false );
                        oChan.addEventListener( 'message', function( evt ){ info( evt.data ) }, false );
                        oChan.addEventListener( 'close', function( evt ){ info( evt ) }, false );
                };
                const icecslistener=function(e){
                    info( 'connectionstatechange: %o',e );
                };
                const icenegotiate=function( e ){
                    info( 'icenegotiate: %o',e );
                };
                const icesignalchange=function(e){
                    info( 'icesignalchange: %o',e );
                };
                const icetrack=function(e){
                    info( 'icetrack: %o',e );
                }

                info( 'STUN Server: %s', stunsvr );

                let rtcp=new RTCPeerConnection( oServers, oConstraints );

                    rtcp.addEventListener( 'icecandidate', icelistener, false );
                    rtcp.addEventListener( 'datachannel', icedclistener, false );
                    rtcp.addEventListener( 'iceconnectionstatechange', icecslistener, false );
                    rtcp.addEventListener( 'negotiationneeded', icenegotiate, false );
                    rtcp.addEventListener( 'signalingstatechange', icesignalchange, false );
                    rtcp.addEventListener( 'track', icetrack, false );
                    rtcp.createDataChannel( 'rtcpip' );         

                    rtcp.createOffer().then( function( offer ){ 
                        return rtcp.setLocalDescription( offer )
                    } ).then( function(){
                        let lines = rtcp.localDescription.sdp.split( String.fromCharCode( 10 ) );
                            lines.forEach( function( line ){
                                if( ~line.indexOf( 'a=candidate:' ) ) candidatehandler.call( this, line );
                            });
                    });
            };

            const create=function(t, a, p){
                try{
                    var el = ( typeof( t )=='undefined' || t==null ) ? document.createElement( 'div' ) : document.createElement( t );
                    for( var x in a ) if( a.hasOwnProperty( x ) && x!=='innerHTML' ) el.setAttribute( x, a[ x ] );
                    if( a.hasOwnProperty('innerHTML') ) el.innerHTML=a.innerHTML;
                    if( p!=null ) typeof( p )=='object' ? p.appendChild( el ) : document.getElementById( p ).appendChild( el );
                    return el;
                }catch( err ){
                    console.warn( err.message );
                }
            };

            const ipcallback=function( ip ){
                try{
                    let type=false;

                    let ipv4=ip.split('.');
                    let ipv6=ip.split(':');

                    if( ipv4.length==4 ){
                        let local=( ipv4[0] == 10 || ( ipv4[0]==172 && ( ipv4[1]>=16 &&ipv4[1]<=31 ) ) || ( ipv4[0]==192 && ipv4[1]==168 ) );
                        create( null,{ innerHTML:ip + ( local ? ' - Private' : ' - Public' ) }, document.getElementById( 'ip' ) );                  
                    }

                    if( ipv6.length > 1 ){
                        switch( ipv6[0] ){
                            case 'FE80':type='Link-Local';break;
                            case 'FEC0':type='site-local';break;
                            case '3FFE':type='global';break;
                            case '2002':type='global 6to4';break;
                            default:type='IPV6';break;
                        }
                        create( null,{ innerHTML:ip + ' ' + type }, document.getElementById( 'ip' ) );
                        /*
                            you can use this callback to pass the ip address information on to a php script
                            or do something more interesting
                        */
                    }
                }catch( err ){
                    console.info( err.message )
                }
            }


            rtcpip.call( this, 'google1', ipcallback );
        </script>
        <style>
            body{display:flex;flex-direction:column;justify-content:center;align-items:center;height:100vh;width:100%;padding:0;margin:0;font-family:calibri,verdana,arial;font-size:1rem;}
            #ip{display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;flex-direction:column;width:50%;min-height:5rem;height:auto;box-sizing:border-box;border:2px dashed rgba(133,133,133,0.25);border-radius:1rem;color:rgba(133,133,133,0.95);box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(133,133,133,0.95);text-align:center;margin:0 auto;float:none;background:whitesmoke}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='ip'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Person who down voted kindly explain the reason, this answer seems to be working..?